# NanoPB Callback functions

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I am working on a project which includes the use of NanoPB.
Currently I have the situation where in my protofile I have multiple callback fields.
I now must encode and decode these callback fields using my own written callback functions.

My question is:

I have a message defined in the protofile which contains callback fields and non callback fields. If I create an callback encode function, should I make this for a specific field or for the entire message?

My protofile looks like this:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message stringCallback{
    required string name = 1;
    required string surname = 2;
    required int32 age = 3;
}
```

An example of encoding a string:

```
bool encode_string(pb_ostream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void * const *arg)
{
    char *str = "Hello world!";
    
    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;
    
    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I create an callback encode function, should I make this for a specific field or for the entire message?

Whatever is most suitable for your purpose.

The example callback you show is not particularly useful. If you only wanted to take a string from `char*`, you could just set `(nanopb).type = FT_POINTER` on the field.

If your callback actions are the same for multiple fields, by all means, reuse the same function. If there is a difference, make separate functions.

Comment: Okay just so I understand it correctly, I can have seperate callback functions for each field of the message. Then I link these to the fields by typing: `msg.name.funcs.encode = function` If I then encode a full msg it will call the encode callback functions of the fields I assigned it to?

Comment: @J.Meulenbeld Yes, callback for each field is called in its turn. The order is determined by the tag numbers in the `.proto` file.